# Getting 'Forward reference needs override' when assembling c with asm on model Large

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos

My code on ASM is a procedure that checks if 'array2' is a permutation of 'array1'. and my code on C has some functions which are coded on my ASM procedures. the mode I use is 'Model LARGE'. (I've done it with 'Model SMALL') and everything was okay.

*I've searched SOF before posting this, and I didn't find a helpful answer.*

> Error: 'Forward reference needs override' (line 41) on line 'CALL
>   _biti'

It does print the output of the code, but still shows the error.

**SOLUTION:** **I just put function _biti's code in the asm file as the first one and not the second one. somehow it solved it.**

'cproc.c'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int biti(unsigned  int n, int i);
extern int compare_i_subset( int arr1[],  int arr2[], int n,
unsigned  int i);
extern int compute_subsets( int arr1[],  int arr2[], unsigned
 int results[],int n, unsigned int p);


int main() {
 int i, n=5, k, arr1[5] = {11, 1, 2, 12, 3}, arr2[5] = {1,  1, 2, 11, 3};
 unsigned  int results[32];
 k = compute_subsets(arr1, arr2, results, n, 32);
 printf("arr1 in reverse order:\n");
 for(i=n-1; i >=0; i--)
  printf("%8d", arr1[i]);
 printf("\narr2 in reverse order:\n");
 for(i=n-1; i >=0; i--)
  printf("%8d", arr2[i]);
 printf("\nSolutions:\n");
 for(i=0; i < k; i++)
  printf("%8d", results[i]);
    return 0;
}//  main
```

'q2large.asm'

```
.MODEL LARGE
.STACK 100H
.DATA
NamMask DW 1

number DW 1
index DW 0
counter DW 0
k DW 0

.CODE


PUBLIC _compare_i_subset
_compare_i_subset PROC FAR

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH DI
PUSH SI
PUSH DX
PUSH BX
PUSH ES

MOV DI, WORD PTR[BP + 6] ;Array1 in DI
MOV SI, WORD PTR[BP + 10] ;Array2 in SI

MOV BX, [BP + 14] ;Assign index
MOV index, BX

MOV DX,  [BP + 16] ;Assign number
MOV number, DX

checkOnBitAg:
PUSH index ; index = 0,1,...,4
PUSH number ; number = 1,2,...,31

; We assign index,counter into function _biti
CALL _biti
ADD SP,4 ; POP index,number

CMP AX,1
JNE checkAgain

;If we get AX=1, lets check arr1[j] <= arr2[j]
MOV ES, WORD PTR[BP+8]
MOV AX, ES:[DI] ;Arr1[0],...,ARR1[4] move into AX
MOV ES, WORD PTR[BP+12]
MOV BX, ES:[SI] ;Arr2[0],...,ARR2[4] move into BX
CMP AX, BX
;If we failed once! EXIT! (return zero, AX = 0)
JA failureNums ; Check next number

;Lets check next 'bit' that is 'ON'
checkAgain:
INC index ;index++
ADD SI,2 ; Because SI is stores INTEGERS!
ADD DI,2 ; Because DI is stores INTEGERS!

CMP index,5
JE finishedAllNums
JMP checkOnBitAg ;Go push again! and check with next index.


finishedAllNums:
MOV AX, 1
JMP FinishFunc2

failureNums:
MOV AX,0

FinishFunc2:
POP ES
POP BX
POP DX
POP SI
POP DI
POP BP
RET
_compare_i_subset ENDP



PUBLIC _biti 
_biti PROC FAR

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH CX
PUSH BX


MOV CX, WORD PTR[BP + 8]
SHL NamMask, CL ;Made a mask
MOV BX,NamMask

AND BX,WORD PTR[BP+6] ;Nam*Mask
CMP BX,0
JE BitNotOn

MOV AX,1
JMP Finish

BitNotOn:
MOV AX,0

Finish:
MOV NamMask,1
POP BX
POP CX
POP BP

RET 
_biti ENDP


PUBLIC _compute_subsets
_compute_subsets PROC FAR

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH DI
PUSH ES

MOV DI, WORD PTR [BP + 14] ; Results in DI
mov ES, WORD PTR [BP + 16]

checkAgain2:
CMP number,31
JG finishedFunc3

PUSH number ; first number will be 1, until 31.
PUSH index ; Initialize index = 0
PUSH DWORD PTR[BP + 10] ; Push address of Arr2
PUSH DWORD PTR[BP + 6] ;Push address of Arr1
CALL _compare_i_subset
ADD SP,12


CMP AX,1
JNE checkAgain4 ; Returned zero (AX = 0)
;else returned AX = 1:
MOV BX,number 
MOV ES:[DI], BX ;Input number into [DI]
ADD DI,2 ; DI hold integers
INC k
JMP checkAgain4

checkAgain4:
INC number ; number++
MOV index, 0
JMP checkAgain2

finishedFunc3:
MOV AX, k
POP ES
POP DI
POP BP
RET
_compute_subsets ENDP
END
```

**Solution code:**

```
    .MODEL LARGE
.STACK 100H
.DATA
NamMask DW 1

number DW 1
index DW 0
counter DW 0
k DW 0

.CODE

_biti PROC FAR
PUBLIC _biti 

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH CX
PUSH BX


MOV CX, WORD PTR[BP + 8]
SHL NamMask, CL ;Made a mask
MOV BX,NamMask

AND BX,WORD PTR[BP+6] ;Nam*Mask
CMP BX,0
JE BitNotOn

MOV AX,1
JMP Finish

BitNotOn:
MOV AX,0

Finish:
MOV NamMask,1
POP BX
POP CX
POP BP

RET 
_biti ENDP

;;

_compare_i_subset PROC FAR
PUBLIC _compare_i_subset

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH DI
PUSH SI
PUSH DX
PUSH BX
PUSH ES

MOV DI, WORD PTR[BP + 6] ;Array1 in DI
MOV SI, WORD PTR[BP + 10] ;Array2 in SI

MOV BX, [BP + 14] ;Assign index
MOV index, BX

MOV DX,  [BP + 16] ;Assign number
MOV number, DX

checkOnBitAg:
PUSH index ; index = 0,1,...,4
PUSH number ; number = 1,2,...,31

; We assign index,counter into function _biti
CALL _biti
ADD SP,4 ; POP index,number

CMP AX,1
JNE checkAgain

;If we get AX=1, lets check arr1[j] <= arr2[j]
MOV ES, WORD PTR[BP+8]
MOV AX, ES:[DI] ;Arr1[0],...,ARR1[4] move into AX
MOV ES, WORD PTR[BP+12]
MOV BX, ES:[SI] ;Arr2[0],...,ARR2[4] move into BX
CMP AX, BX
;If we failed once! EXIT! (return zero, AX = 0)
JA failureNums ; Check next number

;Lets check next 'bit' that is 'ON'
checkAgain:
INC index ;index++
ADD SI,2 ; Because SI is stores INTEGERS!
ADD DI,2 ; Because DI is stores INTEGERS!

CMP index,5
JE finishedAllNums
JMP checkOnBitAg ;Go push again! and check with next index.


finishedAllNums:
MOV AX, 1
JMP FinishFunc2

failureNums:
MOV AX,0

FinishFunc2:
POP ES
POP BX
POP DX
POP SI
POP DI
POP BP
RET
_compare_i_subset ENDP


_compute_subsets PROC FAR
PUBLIC _compute_subsets

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH DI
PUSH ES

MOV DI, WORD PTR [BP + 14] ; Results in DI
mov ES, WORD PTR [BP + 16]

checkAgain2:
CMP number,31
JG finishedFunc3

PUSH number ; first number will be 1, until 31.
PUSH index ; Initialize index = 0
PUSH DWORD PTR[BP + 10] ; Push address of Arr2
PUSH DWORD PTR[BP + 6] ;Push address of Arr1
CALL _compare_i_subset
ADD SP,12


CMP AX,1
JNE checkAgain4 ; Returned zero (AX = 0)
;else returned AX = 1:
MOV BX,number 
MOV ES:[DI], BX ;Input number into [DI]
ADD DI,2 ; DI hold integers
INC k
JMP checkAgain4

checkAgain4:
INC number ; number++
MOV index, 0
JMP checkAgain2

finishedFunc3:
MOV AX, k
POP ES
POP DI
POP BP
RET
_compute_subsets ENDP
END
```

Comment: If you find a solution, please post and accept your answer, rather than updating your question.

Comment: *somehow it solved it.*  Obviously reordering changed the forward ref into a backward ref.